# cannot type anything in visual studio 2010 ide code window

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have visual studio 2010 Premium installed.  It has been working fine for many months.  All of a sudden I opened up a project yesterday and I can no longer type in the ide.

All commands respond to the correct key combination (ex., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to rename), but I can't type any letters, numbers, etc in the code window.  If I start to type, the IntelliSense window opens up, but I cannot add anything from the IntelliSense window if I highlight and hit enter.

Copy and paste does not work. I can highlight in the IDE, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy and paste into notepad.

Up, down, left, right arrow keys work for code navigation.

I can run fine in safe mode.  I uninstalled all plugins and all extensions.  I tried repairing Visual Studio.  I uninstalled and reinstalled.  No luck.

Also, if I try to create new project, I get the error -

> Creating project 'MyProjectName'... project creation failed.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can troubleshoot?